# Solving x^4 - 1 ≡ 0 MOD (55)

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, congruences

My teacher's solution:

a = x^4 - 1 ≡ 0 (5) ==> true for every x≡/≡0 mod (5)

b = x^4 - 1 ≡ 0 (11)==> x≡ +-1 mod (11)

And then solving the 4 systems to find the solutions

However my teacher doesn't explain anything, he just wrote this and I have no idea what he did and how he reached these solutions. I know how to do modulo x^2 but for x^4 I have no idea, or better I had the idea of doing t=x^2 and solving a quadratic modulo but it takes a lot and I'm pretty sure it's not the optimal or intended way

picture of the solution:

[image]

Comment: To start, can you show that $x^4 - 1 = 0 \pmod 5$ for all $x$?

Comment: Also, plan on talking to your teacher about your questions ASAP.  And what four systems are you asking about.  I see only a system of congruences.

Comment: @JalexStark I definitely can, if x=5k+1(or +2 or +3 or +4) then x^4-1 is a multiple of 5, whereas if x=5k x^4-1 is not. However my teacher never solved an exercise using this method so I wasn't aware of it and I don't know in which cases to apply it

Comment: @amWhy english is not my first lang so explaining something about maths clearly is not easy, I added a pic for a better overview

Comment: The assertion about congruence mod. $5$ is just an application of *Fermat's little theorem*.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Dario!  I've embedded it (uploaded it) directly in your post.

Comment: Hopefully you'll soon seek out this [mathjax formatting tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  which gives you much more freedom to express yourself.

Comment: @Dario: I am compelled to point out that mathematics does **not** care what your teacher has solved before, nor what methods he has used before. If you have proven that every integer $x$ is of the form $5k+r$ where $k,r$ are integers and $0 \le r < 5$, then you can logically (mathematically correctly) conclude using this form that $x^4 = (5k+r)^4 \equiv r^4 \pmod{5}$ (do you know why?) and then simply check all $5$ cases. It is also a special case of Fermat's little theorem, which you should learn.

Answer (score 1):

From $\; \begin{cases}x^4\equiv 1\mod 5\iff x\equiv \pm 1,\pm 2\mod 5,\enspace\\x^4\equiv 1\mod 11\iff x\equiv \pm 1 \mod 11,\end{cases} $ we deduce the solutions $\bmod 55$ thanks to the inverse isomorphism in the *Chinese remainder theorem*: let's start from a *Bézout's relation* between $5$ and $11$:
$$1\cdot 11-2\cdot 5=1.$$
The inverse isomorphism  is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/55\mathbf Z \\
(x\bmod 5,y\bmod11)&\longmapsto x\cdot1\cdot 11-y\cdot 2\cdot 5=(11x-10y)\bmod55.
\end{align}
You should find $8$ solutions:
$$x\equiv \pm 1,\pm12,\pm 21\pm 23\mod 55.$$